# Border of UICollectionViewCells doesn't show up for the last two cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The border shows up for all cells except for the last two cells (see screenshot 1). The weird thing is, that the border shows up for the first two cells (see screenshot 2).  Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot 1](http://cl.ly/image/2E0X0k0w0b1a)

[Screenshot 2](http://cl.ly/image/0U1U3K021Q3d)

Comment: Might be useful to know how you're generating the border.

Comment: I simply set the cell properties in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.25;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're drawing a line that's a quarter a pixel wide (on a retina display, an eight of a pixel on a non-retina) in a light color, after all of the scaling, dithering, and clipping (the line is drawn half outside the layer, so that gets clipped) is done, you're not getting anything.  Change the line width to 0.5 (1 retina pixel) and it should work.

Comment: Lower the alpha of the line color, since you're dealing with a sub-pixel line width anyway, that will reduce the dithering and result in a line that seems thinner.

Comment: Still the same problem. The cells are close together. Therefore the border of the last cell is too thin. (See: http://cl.ly/image/2y1m210H1a0E)

Comment: By using the cell layer border property, you're drawing a border on each cell.  Where you have two cells next to each other, you get a line that it twice the width.  At the edges, where you have only one cell, you get a border that's not.  You could try drawing subclassing Cell and drawing your own border in drawRect.  Since view drawing isn't normally clipped to the layer you can actually draw the full width of the line, including the half that normally clipped by the edge of the layer.

Comment: As I thought. I was just hoping that there's an easier way to do that but thank you.